# How to Debug a WPF NET Application in order to detect locks, etc

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-3.5, mdbg

I have a WPF MVVM desktop application in NET 3.5. This application has a combobox in its main window. This comobobx is bound to a view model property. When application is lauched for first time, this combobox is populated. When an item is selected from combobox a wpf datagrid is loaded with data. Then user can do some operations over the data loaded into the datagrid. In order to do a specific operation, user select a row from the datagrid and then clicks on the wpf button which does the desired operation. This operation is done with a background worker and when it finishes the comobox is refreshed. It is refreshed because each item in the combox has a counter associated that needs to be recalculated and then refreshed in the combobox after operation finishes.

My problem is the following: 
Once operation finishes if user clicks on the combobox it freezes and it is not responding during a couple of seconds, aproximately 10 seconds, after that seconds, combobox responds. It only happens in a computer in production environment. In the rest of computers it does not happen. I cannot reproduce it.

So is there any .NET Debugger I can use in order to detect deadlocks, abnormal behaviours in threads, locks, etc.?

I am trying to use MDbg.exe, but from MDbg prompt console, when I try to attach to the process (application running), application freezes...

From MDbg prompt console I use following command to attach to the process:

```
a PID
```

Also, from MDbg prompt console I try to load SOS.dll using below command but it says Extension not found:

```
load sos clr
```

I am not sure if I am using MDbg correctly, I have not used it before.

Comment: I do write outputs to the log in such cases. If you use debugger, then race condition are different.

Comment: Yes, I do write many outputs to a log file but it is difficult to read since this app is multithreading and many background workers write to the log. Furthermore the log is ok, no errors are shown in it. It seems like when user clicks on combobox, combobox freezes during a couple of seconds waiting for something to finish and I cannot see it from logs. So I was searching for a tool to facilitate the debugging proces.

Answer (score 0):

while debugging hit the Pause button on the toolbar and it will break at the current line.

It should give you an idea of what is causing the issue

Comment: ok, it was stopped in a breakpoint so from MDbg command prompt I have typed 'go' command and it continues execution. But then after typing this command I cannot type more commands. I am new with MDbg...